# How to capture a click on a link on a temporary layer that is hidden when the focus changes

Tags: javascript, dom-events

We have a layer that appears when a certain text input has the focus and that should disappear when the input loses the focus. I tried to do it like this:

```
<input type="text" onblur="document.getElementById('hideme').style.display='none'" />
<div id="hideme">Textextext <a href="http://disney.com/">disney</a> text</div>
```

My problem is: when the user clicks on the link link, the browser does not follow this link. It seems the layer disappears before the browser checks where the click goes. What can I do here?

One idea would be to watch whether the mouse enters the `hideme` div and not to close it when the mouse cursor is in there, but this seems way to complicated. Do you have a better idea?

By the way: you can try it out very easy by pasting this into the [Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_try_catch) of w3schools. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution that comes to mind is using `setTimeout` function:

```
<input type="text" onblur="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'hideme\').style.display=\'none\'', 100)" />
```

---

Without freaking slashes:

```
function hidemeWithDelay() {
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('hideme').style.display='none'", 100);
}  

<input type="text" onblur="javascript:hidemeWithDelay();" />
```

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. Thanks! Still, I am wondering whether there is solution that has less of the feeling of a workaround to it. 8-)